# english ivy leaves browning suddenly

Tags: identification, houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, indoors

All of a sudden the leaves started turning brown and shriveling up and it started spreading to other plants. Anyone know the cause of this? The plants get regular water (soil is usually moist) and no getting direct sunlight.

I'm in northeast, tropical climates, and we're experiencing a heat-wave so I've often slept with the fan on.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like tipburn. Perhaps salt has accumulated in the pot, or was left to dry out.

Comment: even without being touched by the sun, a stain spreads on the leaf and is not a dry stain.

Comment: Is there any webbing on the plant, English Ivy is spider mites magnet. Also it can be Thrips as well, which are so tiny most of the times you only see the browning.